# gather() vs pivot_longer() on everything

Tags: r, tidyr

It looks like `pivot_longer()` works like `stack()` so pivoting by rows. In contrast `gather` splitting data by columns.
How I could specify `pivot_longer` to get the same results as `gather()`.
I do not want additional vars and sorting, it is precisely about `pivot_longer` argument.

```
> all.equal(airquality %>% gather(), airquality %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "key", values_to = "value"))
[1] "Attributes: < Component “class”: Lengths (1, 3) differ (string compare on first 1) >"
[2] "Attributes: < Component “class”: 1 string mismatch >"                                
[3] "Component “key”: 764 string mismatches"                                              
[4] "Component “value”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 44 in current 44 in target"
```

Comment: I think this is more suitable at GitHub as "feature request".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I am aware there isn't an option to control the sorting in `pivot_longer` however you can achieve the desired order doing some post processing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

airquality %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "key") %>%
  arrange(match(key, unique(key)))

#    key   value
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 Ozone    41
# 2 Ozone    36
# 3 Ozone    12
# 4 Ozone    18
# 5 Ozone    NA
# 6 Ozone    28
# 7 Ozone    23
# 8 Ozone    19
# 9 Ozone     8
#10 Ozone    NA
# … with 908 more rows
```

---

For data with different classes of column values, we need to convert them to character first. For example with `ggplot2::diamonds` :

```
ggplot2::diamonds %>%      
  mutate(across(.fns = as.character)) %>%     
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "key") %>%     
  arrange(match(key, unique(key)))
```

Comment: I specify that I do not want additional vars and sorting. Even stated  it is precisely about pivot_longer argument. However thanks for the contribution.

Comment: At the top of my answer I mentioned there isn't a `pivot_longer` argument which can get the desired order.

Comment: I give an upvote for the working solution, still I am very surprised that the functions are not easily compatible.

Comment: @polkas They are not supposed to be compatible, pivot_longer is an improved superseding function of gather. See `?gather`, it says "retired, use pivot_longer instead"

Comment: When I have to rewrite all gather/spread in the project I expecting that they make my and other life easier. Functions are retired so influencing the switch.

Comment: the funny case will arise when we run it on ggplot2::diamonds. Even the values_ptypes not help here.

Comment: @RonakShah could you add this one to your answer, thanks.
`ggplot2::diamonds %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "key") %>%
    arrange(match(key, unique(key)))`